# awk catch text going into the next line

Tags: shell, awk

i have the following problem, maybe you can help out:

The text i want to match is like this :

```
Data Generated using Turbine's method
Stuff
more Stuff
Full speed : 0.87
Data generated using My method
Stuff
more stuff
Full speed : 0.96

Data Generated using Turbine's method
Stuff
more Stuff
Full speed : 0.83
Data generated using My method
Stuff
more stuff
Full speed : 0.94
```

I want to match the lines containing full speed and output them into a table like this:

```
Turbine's My
0.87    0.96
0.83    0.94
```

so i can compare the two methods. However i have trouble getting awk to match my current regex which is:

```
/Data Generated using Turbine's method.*Full speed/
/Data Generated using My method.*Full speed/
```

What is my problem exactly? Why doesn't awk match this?

thanks for the advice

Comment: Just so you'll know, in your attempted regex "d*" means "zero or more d". You would want `.*` which means "zero or more of any character" (but this doesn't solve the multi-line issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Turbine\047s" OFS "My"} /Turbine/ {tflag=1; mflag=0} /My/ {mflag=1; tflag=0} /Full speed/ {if (tflag) {T=$2; tflag=0}; if (mflag) { print T OFS OFS $2; mflag=0}}' inputfile
```

On separate lines:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Turbine\047s" OFS "My"}
        /Turbine/ {tflag=1; mflag=0}
        /My/ {mflag=1; tflag=0}
        /Full speed/ {
            if (tflag) {T=$2; tflag=0}; 
            if (mflag) { print T OFS OFS $2; mflag=0}}' inputfile
```

Or a slightly simpler version:

```
awk -F: '/Turbine/, /^Full speed/ {if ($0 ~ /Full/) T=$2}
         /My/, /^Full speed/ {if ($0 ~ /Full/) print T, $2}'
```

Comment: i went with this version because it was simpler to integrate into my script in the end. thanks. actually what does the ~ operator do?

Comment: That's the regular expression matching operator: `string ~ regex` -- http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps

Answer (score 3):

A single RE in AWK only attempts to match against a single line. You seem to want a range pattern, something like: `/^Data Generated/, /^Full Speed.*$/`.

Edit: getting exactly the format you've asked for is *relatively* difficult. If you don't mind turning it sideways, so to speak, so each set is on a line instead of in a column, it becomes rather simpler:

```
/^Data/     { name = $4; }
/^Full/     { speeds[name] = speeds[name] " " $4; } 

END { 
    for (i in speeds)
        printf("%10s : %s\n", i, speeds[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks that captures the line. Didn't even know these exist. if you can tell me how to match the number behind full speed, then that would be perfect

Comment: What do you mean by 'behind full speed?'  $4 is the number when you match /^Full/

Comment: @JimR: His comment above predated the edit, so he was commenting only on the use of a range (which I probably wouldn't have suggested if I'd read his question more carefully to start with).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Perl:

```
perl -ne '
    if (/(\S+) method/) {$method = $1}
    if (/Full speed : ([\d.]+)/) {push @{$speeds{$method}}, $1}
    END {
        @keys = keys %speeds;
        print join("\t", @keys), "\n";
        $max = 0;
        for $v (values %speeds) {
            $len = scalar @$v; 
            $max = $len if $len > $max;
        }
        for $i (0 .. $max-1) {
            for $k (@keys) {print $speeds{$k}[$i], "\t"}; 
            print "\n";
        }
    }
' speed.txt
```

which outputs

```
My      Turbine's
0.96    0.87
0.94    0.83
```

Comment: no thanks its all part of a bigger awk script, but thanks anyway